# What is the default value of the nullable type "int?" (including question mark)?

Tags: c#, integer, nullable

In C#, what is the default value of a class instance variable of type `int?`?

For example, in the following code, what value will `MyNullableInt` have if it is never explicitly assigned?

```
class MyClass
{
    public int? MyNullableInt;
}
```

(It seems likely that the answer is almost certainly either `null` or `0`, but which of those is it?)

Comment: You could have looked [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) - first google hit for me.

Comment: @500 - I did find that article when I was researching -- I actually linked to it in my own answer below -- but as far as I can tell, the article doesn't explicitly state that the default value of a nullable type instance is null.  It *does* say "The default value for HasValue is false. The Value property has no default value", but that doesn't directly answer my original question without some additional digging.

Comment: I wonder if it was because you could just set a breakpoint and see what the value is, or in the Immediate Window type `int? x;` and see what the result is?

Comment: @RufusL I am not well versed in the details of C# but need to move quickly, so it would take an unnecessarily long amount of time for me to test and find every little behavior like this. I do not have to do that for this question thanks to Jon.

Comment: @JamesHurley Ok, I was just theorizing on a possible reason for a downvote to this 7 year old question. But for what it's worth, opening the immediate window, typing `int? x;` and checking the result would take less time than it took you to write that comment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by immediate window, but if you mean writing in my open project, it was not in a buildable state--and because I looked it up, I got from the answer by Jon both the what and the why! I even had enough time to leave a comment defending him, so that I see more answers like it in the future.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

The default value for `int?` -- and for any nullable type that uses the "type?" declaration -- is `null`.

Why this is the case:

- `int?` is syntactic sugar for the type [Nullable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) (where T is `int`), a struct.  ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx))
- The `Nullable<T>` type has a [bool HasValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) member, which when `false`, makes the `Nullable<T>` instance "act like" a `null` value.  In particular, the [Nullable<T>.Equals method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7b1e4z6.aspx)  is overridden to return `true` when a `Nullable<T>` with `HasValue == false` is compared with an actual `null` value.
- From the [C# Language Specification 11.3.4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664475%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), a struct instance's initial default value is all of that struct's value type fields set to their default value, and all of that struct's reference type fields set to `null`.
- The default value of a `bool` variable in C# is `false`  ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx)).  Therefore, the `HasValue` property of a default `Nullable<T>` instance is `false`; which in turn makes that `Nullable<T>` instance itself act like `null`.

Comment: When I change a declaration from `int? x = null;` to `int? x;`, I get compiler errors further down in code: "Use of unassigned local variable x".

Comment: @JohnPick That's a C# compiler feature intended to prevent bugs that might arise from you "forgetting" to initialize a variable before using it. A situation where you *can* encounter an uninitialized int? is when it's a class member variable. Examples of both here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/11/08/c-uninitialized-instance-variables/

Comment: So basically this place is your tech blog? You ask questions for which you just need to run the code to get the answer, then answer the question yourself in the same minute.

Comment: @JonSchneider fair enough, my bad then

Comment: VS's compiler hint/warning is misleading: `Field 'id' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0`. Weird isn't it?

Answer (score 46):

I felt important to share the `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault()` method which is particularly handy when working with math computations that use `Nullable<int>` aka `int?` values. There are many times when you don't have to check `HasValue` property and you can just use `GetValueOrDefault()` instead.

```
var defaultValueOfNullableInt = default(int?);
Console.WriteLine("defaultValueOfNullableInt == {0}", (defaultValueOfNullableInt == null) ? "null" : defaultValueOfNullableInt.ToString());

var defaultValueOfInt = default(int);
Console.WriteLine("defaultValueOfInt == {0}", defaultValueOfInt);

Console.WriteLine("defaultValueOfNullableInt.GetValueOrDefault == {0}", defaultValueOfNullableInt.GetValueOrDefault());
```

[image: Command line showing the code above working]

Comment: I find it confusing that `GetValueOrDefault()` shows 0, when it is null, as shown from the first line.

Comment: It returns the default of `int` instead of `int?`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var x = default (int?);
Console.WriteLine("x == {0}", (x == null) ? "null" : x.ToString());
```