# How get Default Type by System.Nullable from Class just by name?

Tags: c#, class, types, casting

So, i have trouble casting System.Nullables like from int?.

After some research i modifed my code but i dont have any idea how get the type by just Name out of my Class.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < m_textEdits.Count; i++)
        {
            string fieldName = m_textEdits[i].Name.Substring(m_textEdits[i].Name.LastIndexOf("_") + 1);
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo = m_aktuelleZeille.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName);
            if (propInfo != null)
            {
                if (propInfo.GetMethod.ToString().Contains("Null"))
                {
                    propInfo.SetValue(m_aktuelleZeille, m_textEdits[i].EditValue ?? default( IDK WHAT TO PUT IN HERE ));
                }
                else if (propInfo.SetMethod != null) propInfo.SetValue(m_aktuelleZeille, m_textEdits[i].EditValue);
            }
        }
```

m_texedits is List of Textedits, a Textedit is called for example "tb_Menge" so in fieldname stands "Menge" and m_aktuelleZeille is my Class which contains as example:

```
    private int? menge;
    public int? Menge
    {
        get { return menge; }
        set
        {
            if (value != menge)
            {
                menge = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Menge");
            }
        }
    }
```

The else if is working fine, just if i get nullable Types (that why i implented the if)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure exactly what you're asking but I think you're looking to get the default value of the underlying type. e.g. if `int?` then default for int, which is 0?

If that's the case then you can use [`GenericTypeArguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.generictypearguments(v=vs.110).aspx) on the PropertyInfo object which will give you the generic arguments for the `Nullable<T>`, you can then use that to get the default value.

E.g. 
`var defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(propInfo.GenericTypeArguments.First());`

However, I would use caution as the default value for `Nullable<T>` is `null`, not whatever the default of the underlying value is. See [What is the default value of the nullable type "int?" (including question mark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153832/what-is-the-default-value-of-the-nullable-type-int-including-question-mark) for more on this.

Comment: propInfo.Generic ... dont work, i want to cast dynamicly values out of m_textedits[i].editvalue to my class m_aktuelleZeille on property "Menge" as Example. The Problem is normaly it works with the else if in my code but if i have Property in my class like int?, it says i cant cast System.Decimal (Texedit is set to numeric) to System.NullableInt32

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to do. Could you update the question to make it clearer?