# Passing "new int?()" as Parameter

Tags: c#

I'm looking at a function:

```
public void foo(int? id) {
...
}
```

called like:

```
foo(new int?());
```

What is happening here?  What is the value of **id** inside the function when it is passed **new int?()**?  It doesn't *appear* to be anything - the function is using it for a SQL stored procedure, for which I can see in a trace that it is being passed as null.  I'm expecting this stored procedure to be called with a definite, actual integer, and I'm wondering why this code might not be specifying one, unless there is something I'm not understanding about this.

Comment: `int?` is a *nullable integer*.  You're basically passing in `null` to your function and wonder why it isn't a number.  If you want to pass a number, why aren't you?

Comment: what does the procedure do with that value? insert it into a table?

Comment: @Amy Well, I said "probably" - I base my assumption on hints like "I'm looking at a function" and the overall wording of the question. But I could be wrong, I admit.

Comment: `int?` is syntax sugar for `Nullable<int>`.  A struct type, using a new expression to initialize a struct it is standard C# syntax.  Most programmers would prefer `foo(null);` to keep their code readable.

Comment: @Amy That is correct - it is not my code.

Comment: If you feel this is not a duplicate please let me know. I do feel that the accepted answer in the marked duplicate addresses the first 2 questions quit well. The questions about your stored procedure are specific to how your code is structured, if you have questions about what that code does or how it functions I would recommend creating a new question with the specifics about that code.

Comment: "I'm expecting this stored procedure to be called with a definite, actual integer, " why? what does the stored procedure do with that value? what does it do in the case of `null` ?

Comment: It looks up *another* ID in the database based on *that* ID, then uses that new ID in a filter in an update statement - when that filter is WHERE newID = null, it does not find the record to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the value of id inside the function when it is passed new int?()?

`new int?()` is the call of the parameterless constructor of the type nullable int. If you don't pass any value in it it will have the default value `null`. There is a second constructor which can take an `int` number as parameter and initialize it  `new int?(23)`

If you want to see how the constructors work in detail have a look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs)

Answer (score 3):

Because the default value for any `Nullable<T>` type is `null`.

See : [What is the default value of the nullable type "int?" (including question mark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153832/what-is-the-default-value-of-the-nullable-type-int-including-question-mark)

`int?` is a shortcut / syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>`

Answer (score 2):

`int?` is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`, so this:

`new int?()`

is actually passing `null`.