# Default value of nullable enum (Nullable<enum> / enum?)

Tags: c#, enums, nullable

What is the default value of a nullable enum (`Nullable<enum>` / `enum?`)?

```
public enum Days
{
    Sun,
    Mon,
    Tue,
    Wed,
    Thu,
    Fri,
    Sat,
};
```

What will `default(Days?)` evaluate to?

**Intentionel duplicate** of [What is the default value of the nullable type “int?” (including question mark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153832/what-is-the-default-value-of-the-nullable-type-int-including-question-mark). If you don't know that nullable integer (`int?`) acts the same as nullable enum (`enum?`), you do not know that the question is the same, and therefore do not read the question nor its answers.

Comment: If you need evidence to be satisfied, see [here](http://rextester.com/BSBYL27302). Also, take a read of the [`nullable<T>` source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs)

Comment: Default value of any Nullable<> is null